# Passing parameters to @Configuration in Spring

Tags: spring

I have a requirement of creating a prototype bean that's stateful, i.e. take parameters in constructor.

I tried to use @Configuration to create that bean, but found it doesn't work if I use a parameterized constructor...

Note that the parameters I want to pass are NOT spring beans...they are simple POJOs...so I can't autowire them.

So this is what I want to do -

---

```
@Configuration
public class MyClassFactory {

@Bean
public MyClass getMyClass(Pojo1 pojo1, Pojo2 pojo2) {

    return new MyClass (pojo1, pojo2);
}

}
```

---

```
@Scope("PROTOTYPE")
public class MyClass {

public MyClass(Pojo1 pojo1, Pojo2 pojo2) {
...
}

@Autowired SomeService1 service1;
@Autowired SomeService1 service2;

...

}
```

Of course I can make MyClass applicationContextAware, and pick up services from it, rather than making it a prototype bean...but was wondering why above pattern is not allowed...

Comment: Check out [SPR-7431](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7431) - hope I can fix it soon.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz your [pull request on Github](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/pull/84) is almost in but needs few fixes suggested by cbeams ;)

Comment: @Xaerxess: I know, I just didn't have time to clean it up thoroughly. But stay tuned!